# ¿Cómo enviar datos a un Select con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, twig

La idea general es mandar datos mediante JavaScript a un modal para realizar la función de editar datos, funciona, pero no logro que el campo cargo, se muestre en un select.

**Mi Select:** El for muestra una lista de cargos (Vendedor y Supervisor)

```
<div class="col-6">
   <label class="control-label">Cargo</label>
        <div>
          <select name="edit_empleado_cargo" class="form-control input-lg" id="edit_empleado_cargo">
           {% for rc in resultcargo %}
               <option value="{{rc.id}}">{{rc.nombrecargo}}</option>
           {% endfor %}
         </select>
       </div>
</div>
```

**Mi Funcion JS:** Los otros campos funcionan, llenan los input type="text" del formulario.

```
  $('#editarempleado').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
      var button = $(event.relatedTarget);

      var vars = button.data('stuff');

      $('#edit_empleado_id').val(vars[0]);
      $('#edit_empleado_nombre').val(vars[1]);
      $('#edit_empleado_apellidos').val(vars[2]);
      $('#edit_empleado_direccion').val(vars[3]);

      $('#edit_empleado_cargo').val(vars[4]);

      $('#edit_empleado_telf').val(vars[5]);
      $('#edit_empleado_cel').val(vars[6]);
      $('#edit_empleado_feingreso').val(vars[7]);
      $('#edit_empleado_salario').val(vars[8]);
      $('#edit_empleado_comision').val(vars[9]);
      $('#edit_empleado_password').val(vars[10]);

  });
```

**Mi Resultado:** Aparece vacio y solo aparecen las opciones al abrir el select, pero no el valor que mande.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> **Aclaraciones: Cuando le quito el id al select, la lista aparece, pero claro, ya no podria manejarla con JS. GRACIAS**

Comment: Asegúrate que el valor que le mandas es el mismo que el value que debe tener, porque si le mandas el texto "Vendedor" o "Supervisor" entonces no va a funcionar. Aquí me funciona aparéntemente bien: https://jsfiddle.net/tykzg3fL/

Comment: Me sirvio, gracias, esa era la soluciona.

Comment: Vale, lo he agregado como respuesta, para que la pregunta no quede pendiente eternamente. La cual puedes aceptar o bien puedes borrar toda la pregunta, lo que prefieras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asegúrate que el valor que le mandas es el mismo que el value que debe tener, porque si le mandas el texto "Vendedor" o "Supervisor" entonces no va a funcionar. Aquí me funciona aparéntemente bien:

```js
$('#edit_empleado_cargo').val("24");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-6">
   <label class="control-label">Cargo</label>
        <div>
          <select name="edit_empleado_cargo" class="form-control input-lg" id="edit_empleado_cargo">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="23">Vendedor</option>
          <option value="24">Supervisor</option>
         </select>
       </div>
</div>
```